# How do I form body in a request manually in Groovy

Tags: rest, groovy, multipartform-data

I have the following example of a request which returns 201 as expected. The headers are:

[image]

And the main request body itself looks like this:
[image]
The problem is that this request is of `multipart/from-data`
 content type. I've never worked with that. So, the main request actually contains of two smaller ones which have their own duplicate headers. I have no idea how to build this with groovy. Also, I need to  pass `Authorization` and `Content-Type` headers to the main request. What should I do? Is there a way to manually form body with all the headers? If so, how do I build it using groovy's `RESTClient`?

I wish I could do something like:

```
def http = new HTTPBuilder("URL");

def token = "mytoken";

http.setHeader("Authorization", auth);
http.setContentType("multipart/form-data; boundary=W3NByNRZZYy4ALu6xeZzvWXU3NVmYUxoRB");

http.request(Method.POST) {

MultipartEntity jsonEntity = new MultipartEntity();
jsonEntity.addPart("", new JSONObject("{"values":{"Incident Number":"INC000036078321","Work Log Type":"General Information","Description":"test","z2AF Work Log01":"book.xlsx"}}")) //nevermind escaping

jsonEntity.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "form-data");
jsonEntity.setHeader("name", "entry");
jsonEntity.setHeader("Content-Type", "form-data");
jsonEntity.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "application/json");
jsonEntity.setHeader("charset", "UTF-8");
jsonEntity.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");


MultipartEntity base64Entity = new MultipartEntity();
base64Entity.addPart("", "loooooooooooooooooonng base64");

base64Entity.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "form-data");
base64Entity.setHeader("name", "attach-z2AF Work Log01");
base64Entity.setHeader("filename", "book.xlsx");
base64Entity.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
base64Entity.setHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "base64");

http.addMultipartEntity(jsonEntity);
http.addMultipartEntity(base64Entity);


        response.success = { resp, json ->
            result = json;
        }
}
```

But unfortunately I can't do that because there's no `setHeader` for `MultipartEntity` and no `addMultipartEntity` for `HTTPBuilder`. How can I do that anyway?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.tothenew.com/blog/groovy-http-builder-for-sending-multipart-file/

Comment: Ok, but there's no info about headers on `MultipartEntity`

Comment: each entity has only standard headers and they are generated automatically for each entity type.